# css changed in production

Tags: css, angular, ngx-datatable

I'm creating the angular 6 application. All working fine. But css getting problem in production build. I didn't know what's happening there. I'm using `ngx-datatable` to show the table.

This is the css I've used

```
datatable-scroller datatable-row-wrapper {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9999992e;
}
```

## Local serving table screenshot

[image]

But it's not a problem in local. In production the colour gets gone. This is the css I've got in live.

```
datatable-scroller datatable-row-wrapper {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

## Live serving table screenshot

[image]

See the difference, In local there's no border bottom line in table. But in live colour in css gets gone and also table gets split by lines. And also in live left half table gets line and right half not. I'm really confusing with that. Can someone please help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do a `--prod` build in local is this issue happening?

Comment: yes I'm doing `ng build --prod ` for building production. I don't know why this issue ocuuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is in your **8-digit** Hex color code. It works for android. I will suggest you to use 6-digit hex code or rgba() format color code for any web application.

Comment: Okay fine I'll check that also. But may I know why this issue occurring because this is also a color code right?

Comment: web uses #99992e prob ignoring your invalid color code

Comment: I have edited my answer. This 8-digits hex code are used for andoid not for web, so it will ignore that.

Comment: yes that's my issue. I changed my hex code now it's working fine. Thanks @danday74